# If $|G| > 2$ and $G$ is simple then $G \subset A_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ letters.

Let $A_n$ be the alternating group on $n$ letters.

Suppose $G \leq S_n$.

Prove that if $|G| >2$ and $G$ is simple then $G \subset A_n$.

Is it possible to suppose $\gamma \in G$ is odd and then construct a group homomorphism $f :G \rightarrow G$ such that $ker(f) \neq \{e\}$ and $ker(f) \neq G$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $G$ is a simple group?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I edited the question.

Comment: Look at the subgroup $G\cap A_n$, it's either $G$ or a subgroup of index $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the homomorphism $f:G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_2}$ given by $f(g)=sgn(g)$ where $sgn(g)$ is the sign of the permutation $g$ (viewed as an element of $S_n$). Now, since $G$ is simple, ker$f$ is either trivial, or all of $G$. What does ker$f$ trivial mean in terms of signs of elements of $G$? Can you derive a contradiction?

Comment: Just so I understand. If $\sigma \in G$ is even, then $f(\sigma)=0$. Is that correct or is it the other way around?

Comment: @user151852: That's correct. This is the definition I had in mind.

Comment: It means that the only even permutation of $G$ is $id$. Thus, $G\cap A_n = id$. This is a contradiction because if $G\cap A_n = id$, then $|G| \leq 2$. Correct?